# How to use multiline-string here-doc with interpolation using enumerable or loop blocks

Tags: ruby

I want to simulate the usage of ERB templates using blocks into multiline-heredoc in Ruby:

### Example:

#### From:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <% @greetings.each do |greeting| %>
        <li><%= greeting %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Into:

```
greetings = ['Hello World', 'Hello Earth', 'Hello Mars']

body = (
  <<-eos
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        #{
        greetings.map do |greeting|
          <<-eos2
          <li>#{greeting}</li>
          eos2
        end.join
        }
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
  eos
)
```

^ The above seems to work, but it breaks the syntax highlighting in Atom, and looks very messy to me. Perhaps there's an easier way I hope?

```rb
puts body
#  <html>
#    <body>
#      <ul>
#        <li>Hello World</li>
#<li>Hello Earth</li>
#<li>Hello Mars</li>
#
#      </ul>
#    </body>
#  </html>
```

#### Background:

- I am writing inline into the `.rb` file multiline-string of "example" html values using `factory_bot`

#### Other Attempt:

Tried below, but I'm getting syntax errors:

```
greetings = ['Hello World', 'Hello Earth', 'Hello Mars']

body = (
  <<-eos
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        #{greetings.each do |greeting|}
          <li>#{greeting}</li>
        #{end}
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
  eos
)
```

*P.S. I am aware that I can move the whole thing into an `.erb` file, but I am more curious to know if there's a way to do it inline, i.e. (for very short strings that need not be moved into a separate `.erb`*

### Update:

Thanks to @AlekseiMatiushkin, I resolved the syntax highlighting, I'll still open this question up, just in case anyone finds a simpler way, to do the looping:

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

^ also, I thought that I had to use `<<-html2` inside the `<<-html` block, because I thought it would break it, but seems like nested `<<-html` still worked, so, good! :)

### Update:

Unfortunately, reopening the file caused the syntax highlighting to break again. But, I guess, this should be fine for now :)

[image]

Comment: `<<-eos` → `<<-html`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin ahh is it better to use `html` (or more specific jargon?). Because I just always use `eos` for multiline-strings all-the-time :) or does the name have an actual effect or something?

Comment: It’s how editors guess the desired syntax highlighting for heredocs in general.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin ahh I didn't know that! Thanks! Cool! :) It looks much better now only except the first line `body`. I'll post screenshots before and after. Thanks!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks! And oh correction from my last comment, the first line: "body" was still breaking syntax highlighting but only when I used `<<-html2` inside `<<-html`. Didn't know I could nest them with same name (`<<-html`) (as screenshot above), so after I did, all was correctly highlighting now! :) Still looks a bit ugly, but a lot better!!!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin oh! When I closed the `.rb` file in Atom, and reopened it again, the syntax highlighting still breaks (I'll upload another screenshot)! xD But thanks a lot! This should be fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Won't mark this solved as this isn't a direct answer to my question, but is a direct solution to my problem, as I still wasn't able to solve this in pure here-doc, but that I was able to solve my problem upon a realisation that I can also use ERB inline with here-doc string. But, if it helps anyone, here:

```
require 'erb'

greetings = ['Hello World', 'Hello Earth', 'Hello Mars']

body = ERB.new(
  <<-html
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <% greetings.each do |greeting| %>
          <li><%= greeting %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
  html
).result(binding)

puts body
#  <html>
#    <body>
#      <ul>
#        
#          <li>Hello World</li>
#        
#          <li>Hello Earth</li>
#        
#          <li>Hello Mars</li>
#        
#      </ul>
#    </body>
#  </html>
```

*P.S. To be able to indent code without affecting the here-doc string, and if you are using Ruby >= 2.3, it's better to use the squiggly-heredoc literal: [`<<~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html). However, if you're using Ruby < 2.3 but are using Rails, you can use the [`.strip_heredoc`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/strip_heredoc) instead.*